# Projecting rasterLayer to calculate slope with terrain() function in R

Tags: r, projection, raster, terrain

I have the following raster layer which I would like to project, so then I can calculate the slope using `terrain()` function. This is not real spatial object, just theoretical surface, so I need some simple projection for it.
I try to do this in the second part of the code but for some reason I am receiving error messages and I don't know why is that the case.

```
location <- 0       # location/distance parameter
s <- 1          # scale
inc <- 0.1  # increment for sequencing y axis
increment <- rev(seq(-6,6,inc))   # Create a sequence of x values (reverse)

y <- 1/(1+ exp(-(increment/s)))

# Create matrix:
rep <- length(increment)
valuematrix <- replicate(rep,y)

# Create raster
raster <- raster(valuematrix, xmn=0,xmx=13,ymn=0,ymx=13)
```

Assigning projection and calculating slope:

```
newproj <-  CRS("+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84")

proj4string(raster) <- newproj

terrain(raster,alt='slope')
```

Error message:

```
Error in isLonLat(out) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Neither can I. Update `raster` package and try a fresh R session?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I upgraded R to 3.2.2 (from 3.2.0) and it did the trick.